# Get a custom dimension dynamically from Google Analytics API

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way of getting data from GA API, including a custom dimension in a dynamic way?

I run this code:

```
startDate="YYYY-MM-DD"
endDate="YYYY-MM-DD"
viewID="ga:XXXXXXXX"
dim=XX

query.list<-Init(
    start.date=startDate,
    end.date=endDate, 
    dimension="print(paste0('ga:dimension',dim), quote=FALSE), ga:date", 
    metrics="ga:sessions",
    sort="-print(paste0('ga:dimension',dim), quote=FALSE)",
    max.results=10000,
    table.id=viewID  
)

ga.query<-QueryBuilder(query.list)
ga.data<-GetReportData(ga.query,token,paginate_query = T, split_daywise = T)
```

and the output is:

Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) : 
code : 400 Reason : Invalid value 'print(paste0('ga:dimension',dim),quote=FALSE),ga:date'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(ga:.+)?'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get rid of the double quotes in all of your expressions like this one: `"print(paste0('ga:dimension',dim), quote=FALSE), ga:date"` -- that is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lourdes, you write print&paste functions between " ", Init function reads them as character, not as a function. Try this:

```
startDate="YYYY-MM-DD"
endDate="YYYY-MM-DD"
viewID="ga:XXXXXXXX"
dim=XX
query.list<-Init(
            start.date=startDate,
            end.date=endDate, 
            dimension=paste(toString(paste("ga:dimension", dim, sep="")), "ga:date",sep=", "),
            metrics="ga:sessions",
            sort=toString(paste("-ga:dimension", dim, sep="")),
            max.results=10000,
            table.id=viewID  
        )

ga.query<-QueryBuilder(query.list)
ga.data<-GetReportData(ga.query,token,paginate_query = T, split_daywise = T)
```

For custom dimensions 1,5,11 write:

```
 dim=c("1","5","11")
```